# Find an example of $f \in PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$ that gives an isometry of $\mathbb{H}$ with Riemannian metric

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, mobius-transformation

I started studying on differential and projective geometry and I came across the following question on which I have diffuculties to solve/find examples:

Let $\mathbb{H}$ = { $z \in \mathbb{C}$ | $Im(z)$} > $0$

Consider the 1D complex projective space $P_1(\mathbb{C})$. Recall that the group $PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$ of projective transformations of $P_1( \mathbb{C})$ consists of the maps

$f = \displaystyle{\frac{az + b}{cz + d}}$, where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ad - bc = 1$

- Find an example of $f \in PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$ that gives an isometry of
  $\mathbb{H}$ with Riemannian metric $\displaystyle{\frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}}$ but is not an isometry of $\mathbb{C}$ with the Euclidean metric $dx^2+ dy^2$
- Find a converse example.

So my question is how can I find such examples and which steps do I need to prove that its a valid example.

I tried $f(z) = -z$ as an example but I am stuck at proving an isometry in $\mathbb{H}$

Comment: One way you find examples is to make guesses and test them. On this problem, you could guess a particular element of $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$ and test it. What guesses did you make, and how did you test them?

Comment: I tested f(z) = -1/z and found that $f: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$, however I am lost on proving that it is an isometry of $\mathbb{H}$ with the riemannian metric.

Comment: You should show that every $f\in \Bbb PSL(2,\Bbb C)$ in fact is an isometry of $\Bbb H$ with the hyperbolic metric.

Answer (score 2):

How about scaling ? $f(z) = az/(1/a) = a^2 z$ i.e., $d = 1/a$, $b=c=0$ and $a>0$ and $a \neq 1$ is a positive real number, is an isometry in the Riemannian metric but not an isometry in Euclidean metric.

Comment: And how exactly do I show that its an isometry in the Riemannian metric? Thats the part I am stuck with...

Comment: $d(a^2 z_1,a^2 z_2) = \int_t \frac{\sqrt{a^4x'(t)^2+a^4y'(t)^2}}{a^2y(t)} = \int_t \frac{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}}{y(t)} = d(z_1,z_2)$. So an isometry. i.e., in integral use $a^2 \gamma(t)$ and $a^2$ gets cancelled.

Comment: Thankyou! This is very helpful!

Comment: And for convenience, what is the reason its not an isometry in the euclidean metric?

Comment: For Euclidean metric : $d(z_1,z_2) = |z_1-z_2 | \neq a^2 \times |z_1-z_2| = d(a^2 z_1,a^2 z_2)$

Comment: And are you able to give me also a converse example?

Comment: what exactly u r asking for by converse ? it seems from other's comments, any transformation from PSL is a Riemannian metric Isometry.

Comment: With the converse I mean that its an isometry in the euclidean metric but not in the riemannian metric.

Answer (score 0):

Take any element of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$, it will work. You need real coefficients, and positive determinant of the rational transformation to invariate $\mathbb{H}$ at the least.

Comment: okay thanks! Is there a possibility you can show how to prove an isometry then? Thats the part I am stuck at.

Comment: Especially for the riemannian metric